# Get Request/Response Body&Header in Spring AOP

Tags: spring, http, aop, spring-aop, spring-boot-actuator

I want to get request/response body and header within my aspect before and after if it's available or how to get those .

I mean i think with before  annotation should be work for request,

with after annotation should be work for response. Can be ?

**What I've tried so far :**

I tried logbook library it's very complicated for me i could'nt figured it out how to work with that.So i gave up.

The actuator can do trick but I am doing extra work like how many times the endpoints called etc.So therefore i can't use actuator.

Also i tried to get request headers like below at least but i think this headers coming same all the time.I couldn't get httpservletresponse like how httpservetrequest does.

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                .getRequest();
```

then
`request.getHeader("date")` but what about requestbody ?

how to get requestbody ? responsebody ? repsonseheader ?

My aspect file :

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AppAspect implements ResponseInfo{

    @Before("execution(@(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping *) * *(..))")
    public void loggingStartPointRequests(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                .getRequest();

}

@After("execution(@(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping *) * *(..))")
    public void loggingEndPointRequests(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws IOException {

    }

}
```

My Controller Class:

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/people") // 
    public ResponseEntity<Poeple> getAllPeople(@RequestParam(name = "page", required = false) Integer page,
            @RequestParam(name = "size", required = false) Integer size,
            @RequestParam(name = "sortBy", required = false) Boolean sortByNameOrEpCount) {
doSomething();
}

}
```

Comment: Request and response body can be read only once unless some special processing is done. Could you also update the question with the requirement or the reason you want these to be read in an aspect ?

Comment: Actually there is no requirement to use Aspect. If we can do it in controller method somehow that should be ok though.So I mean can we take all header and body inside controller methods ? I just thought getting request and response header body only can getting inside aspect . There for i asked that .

Comment: Aspect or not , request / response body can be read only once unless it is manipulated to be re-readable . People knowledgeable can share ideas if you can update the requirement on why you need those information in the controller. What is the purpose of getting request/response body ?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and if you have your `@Aspect` annotated with `@Component` (or any `@Autowired` candidate) you can simply get the `HttpServletRequest` like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SomeAspect {
    
   @Autowired
   HttpServletRequest request;

   @Before("...")
   public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint jp){
       /* You will have the current request on the request property */
      System.out.println(request.getRequestURL());
   }  
}
```

I know this is an old question but I hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to implement the interface [HandlerInterceptor](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor), it would help you being able to inspect the request and the response. For example:

```
public class ApiMonitor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
    // when the client access to your endpoint
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    // when you finished your process 
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
    // after you already returned an answer to the client
}
}
```

If you want to operate with the object that you're returning just before you send it to the client, then you need AOP, yes. That's an example of how I do it to modify an object on certain endpoints just before it's parsed to json.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class MyCustomAOPInterceptor {

/**
* These poincuts check the execution of a method in any (*) 
* class of my.package.controller and that start with
* get/list/find plus any other word (*) . For example
* my.package.controller.UserController.getUserById()
*/
@Pointcut("execution(* my.package.controller.*.get*(..))")
public void petitionsStartWithGet() { }

@Pointcut("execution(* my.package.controller.*.list*(..))")
public void petitionsStartWithList() { }

@Pointcut("execution(* my.package.controller.*.find*(..))")
public void petitionsStartWithFind() { }

@AfterReturning(pointcut = "petitionsStartWithGet() || petitionsStartWithList() || petitionsStartWithFind()", returning = "result")
public void translateEntities(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
    // do your stuff; result is the object that you need
}

}
```